If you believe that our reality is some kind of reflection, what should be your label? Atheist? Nonbeliever? Agnostic?
If you believe in the external presence (God), but you are not religious in a conventional way. You believe in destiny, guidance from above, the afterlife, but you don't believe that Jesus Christ or Allah is responsible for that. Then, what should they call you?

Possibly resident of his/her dream world.

"It is not the name you call me that matters, only the name to which I respond."

I think you would just be theist, more specifically a monotheist, a non religious theist.

Its fairly mainstream if you look up epistemological scepticism or indirect realism. Some notable examples
Plato
The intelligible world — often miscalled the world of Forms — is the reality.Today we just call it The Platonic Realm.
The sense-able world is the shadow world.
Best seen as the allegory of the cave
Kant

We have sufficiently proved … that everything intuited in space or in time, hence all objects of an experience possible for us, are nothing but appearances

We are stuck under the terms of space-time via our perceptions to see only phenomena.
What really exists — the thing in itself — is the noumena that we can never see or know directly
Vedanta
The world is the unreal.
The reality is Brahman.
A gossamer-thin but uncrossable barrier separates the two — maya.
The word ved-anta — knowledge-end (limit) — in itself tells a tale:
What we wish to know cannot be known; what we know is worthless/unreal.
It is summarized in the three lines

Brahma satya
Jagat mithya
Jivao brahmaiva naapara

Brahman is real
The world is unreal
The soul and the absolute reality are identical
Plotinus, Gnostics
I would suggest you reflect on Plotinus. In some way he is the mystical completion of Plato.
Also consider the Gnostics.  Especially since you are very drawn to the Matrix ideas, I think you will find the basic gnostic idea attractive: an ignorant/malevolent God who creates (Demiurge) and a supreme God (Pleroma) that is only accessible when the the creator-God is transcended via gnosis.
See The Gnostic Gospels
Added Later
... in response to comments/questions

Question: What is the point of meditation? Where is knowledge? If it is reality in a dream, or, dream in reality, or dream in a dream - it does not give knowledge.

Have you tried it?
A certain mystic guru who I know indirectly says:

People say that mantras don't work because they mean or signify anything but simply by focusing the mind. ie (they claim) repeating Coca-cola and repeating Om namah Shivaya are equivalent. I say to them are you speaking after trying or are you just imagining and pushing your preconceptions?
I am ready to challenge anyone: Repeat coca-cola a million times and repeat Om namah Shivaya (or any sacred mantra) a million times and then tell me they are the same!

Here are some more established mystic sources who authoratively assert that meditation is a legitimate source of knowledge (from chatGPT)

Meister Eckhart: The eye with which I see God is the same eye with which God sees me.

Rumi: Silence is the language of God, all else is poor translation.

St. Teresa of Ávila: Prayer is an act of love; words are not needed. Even if sickness distracts from thoughts, all that is needed is the will to love.

St. John of the Cross: In the inner stillness where meditation leads, the Spirit secretly anoints the soul and heals our deepest wounds.

Ramana Maharshi: Silence is truth. Silence is bliss. Silence is peace. And hence Silence is the Self.

The Dalai Lama: The purpose of our lives is to be happy. Happiness is not something ready made. It comes from your own actions.

Thomas Merton: Happiness is not a matter of intensity but of balance, order, rhythm, and harmony.




Question: Religion is part of a dream. You can believe in it, it is real. But I am interested in a programming language that programmed this dream together with this religion

Why/how to you distinguish the Matrix as special?
The Matrix is mythology.
Harry Potter is mythology.
So is Krishna, Abraham, Jesus...
All of them have their specific nuance and finesse — I value all of them... as mythology.
For me the touchstone is like this:
Where there are events, people, commotion... happiness, sadness,,, life,death... fear, bliss... As Kant so profoundly points out where there is space and time that is a dream world.
Where there is awareness it is waking
Factually speaking we always have elements of both.
Above I quoted 7 well known figures under 3 standard systems that chatGPT chose to give. There are dozens of systems and hundreds of figures.  But behind this bewildering cornucopia of systems, methods, techniques there is a very simple basic intention:
Increase the awareness; decrease the drama.

You can repeat hundreds of times that everything is unreal, when you meditate or when you drink alone.
But how can that advance our understanding of our reality?

@TheMatrixEquation-balance One day, you see through the illusion.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance Every morning when you awake you get a foretaste of an answer to your query: There is a moment, ok maybe a few seconds, when the entire frame is invalidated and you say Oh! That was a dream; this is «reality».  Our mistake is we invest in the "reality" not the "dream"; but in fact everything is a dream. As Jung said: He who looks outwards dreams, he who looks inward awakens

@Rushi - What is the point of meditation? Where is knowledge? If it is reality in a dream, or, dream in reality, or dream in a dream - it does not give knowledge.

Ive added a Added Later @TheMatrixEquation-balance

It's somewhat silly to say "repeating Coca-cola and repeating Om namah Shivaya are equivalent", because most people have a strong mental association to what Coca-Cola means, whereas merely claiming "Om namah Shivaya" is mystical would bias people towards seeing that as mystical. If you wanted to actually test whether the words are mystical, you should gather a bunch of people (who've never heard these words), tell some to repeat "Om namah Shivaya" and tell others to repeat some gibberish that contains similar sounds. My hypothesis: they'll get similar results in a proper scientific study.

... If both a "mystical" phrase and gibberish end up with some positive effect, some gullible person will probably say "we've found a new mystical phrase!", and rather than accepting falsification, they'll just burrow themselves into an unfalsifiable position. Also, if you take 1 second to say each of those phrases (1 second is probably generous), it would take 11 days non-stop to say it a million times, which is probably a bit too much to ask for. You'd get through a bit more than 4000 an hour.

@Rushi - "The Matrix is mythology.
Harry Potter is mythology." - If things have similarities, you cannot assume they are equal. You can make a very believable movie, and you can make a simulator indistinguishable from reality. But you cannot have a functional and developing world in the movie. It will always be a reflection on some level of quality.

@NotThatGuy Yeah 1 /sec = 3600 /hr = million /11½ days. But why is that a thing? No one who uses mantras treats them as one-off. Its always a regimen requirement. Its like you go to a doc with high BP or sugar and he says One hour walk will help you. It obviously means on a regular basis. If one single 1 hour walk would solve sugar/BP issues no one would have these!! Likewise here also: eg. a Hindu who takes the Ram mantra, expects to do it millions of times in their lifetime, point being that he will die saying it.

Gandhi is considered to be a saintly figure because (among other things) he fell to the assassin's bullet saying Oh! Ram!, rather than, say, Oh! Ive been shot! This mystic I referred above would like his folks to do their (Buddhist) mantras like hundred-thousand per month (as best as I know). So his experiment amounts to a 1 year trial (at this rate)

@Rushi Your so-called "guru" is offering a "challenge" to repeat BOTH a million times. You're saying that might be spread across an entire lifetime for someone who believes that stuff. But that's largely irrelevant, because the challenge is presumably for people who don't believe it, and expecting someone to dedicate that amount of time to testing something they don't believe in is entirely unreasonable. So it's a rather empty challenge, with little risk that someone would take them up on that (although most people probably have better things to do than spend even an hour on that).

I dont understand your arithmetic @NotThatGuy. At < 3000 a day its 1 year; at 6000 a day its 6 months. So you (or whoever wants to try!) can reasonably do the experiment, by trying both in a year. ...most people probably have better things to do than spend even an hour on that.  There you are!  You've demonstrated his real point!  You would not spend an hour but pass judgement on people who choose to spend their lives on such. Would you apply the same manner on a medicine student who spends 5 years or a music student who spends 10 and prejudge their activities as meaningless without trying?

@Rushi Would you spend a year testing the existence of auras, another year testing the efficacy of crystals, another testing the efficacy of astrology, another testing the efficacy of homeopathy, and a bunch more years testing the truth of ghosts, various proposed deities, aliens, bigfoot, and every pseudoscience you don't believe is true? That's an absurd expectation. Would you spend even an hour on each? I doubt it. And medicine and music are terrible analogies because medicine is well-demonstrated and music doesn't make claims of truth (beyond like "that sounds nice" or whatever).

@Rushi We differentiate pseudoscientific nonsense from truth through scientific experimentation. Maybe you can convinced some scientists to perform that test for you (with the improvements I noted) in a controlled setting and publish it in a peer-reviewed journal. Until that happens, we'll just leave it in the trash with all the other pseudoscience. Also, if you've demonstrated that "saying these words a bunch makes me feel nice and saying these a bunch don't", all you've demonstrated is that there's something different about those words, which is a long way from showing them to be "sacred".

A theist believes in the existence of some being (deity) beyond what we can see (who's usually conscious and has some broad authority or power over and concern with reality and humanity).
This can include any deity (or set of deities) and isn't specific to Jesus or Allah.
There are different types of theists. The most noteworthy may be these: A pantheist believes that the universe itself is identical to a deity (whatever that means). This often seems to be conflated with deism, where the existence of a deity is revealed through nature (and they're often conceived of as a non-intervening creator of the universe). Whether these fall within the label of "theism" is arguable - many would say they don't.

An atheist doesn't believe (or lacks belief) in any such being. This includes both strong/positive atheism (believing that no gods exist) and weak/negative atheism (merely lacking a belief in any deity).
An agnostic considers the existence of a deity to be unknown or unknowable. This, generally and technically speaking, falls under (weak) atheism, although many (non-theist) agnostic laypeople take issue with this classification. But I'd draw a separation here with agnostic theists, who consider the existence of a deity to be unknown or unknowable, but who still believe in one or more (these obviously aren't atheists).
The most vocal atheists tend to be skeptics leaning towards (or calling themselves) naturalists, i.e. they don't accept any sort of supernatural forces (typically due to a lack of good evidence or other justification). But someone can be an atheist and still believe in destiny or some afterlife or ghosts or magical crystals or auras or whatever.

Based on what you describe, it sounds like you'd fall under theism, but you can judge that for yourself based on the definitions provided.
Belief in an external presence, in itself, wouldn't necessarily classify as theism. This could include belief that we live in a simulation, which needn't involve anything defined as a "deity" (although the simulation itself may or may not contain deities, and one can probably argue whether the simulators could be said to classify as deities to us). But you did label this presence "God", and you speak of guidance from above, so maybe you're assigning some additional traits to such a presence that could classify it as a deity.

"A theist believes in the existence of some being (deity) beyond what we can see" - I have a hard time to attribute this classical description of supreme being - to a normal programmer-architect who designed our Matrix.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance it sounds like you'd fall under theism This answer comes from a place of fitting all religions into the Christian mold. And therefore equating theism with religion. But even staying within the Christian fold there are great variations. There are schools that emphasize the Holy Spirit over Father and Son — think Pentecostals, Quakers all the way back to Basil, Gregory and the gnostic mystics. In modern times the centering prayer of Fr. Keating was so popular that he was censured for being a crypto eastern mystic pretending christianity!! These are borderline theis

@Rushi "This answer comes from a place of fitting all religions into the Christian mold" - excuse me? This answer applies to many forms of theism, including those outside of Christianity. It's not my fault that there's similarity between Christianity and other religions. Although I certainly didn't aim to detail every single form of theism, but rather just to give a brief overview of it.

@Rushi - Religion is part of a dream. You can believe in it, it is real. But I am interested in a programming language that programmed this dream together with this religion.

Why/How is that programming language not part of the dream @TheMatrixEquation-balance?

@NotThatGuy Theism is about a personal god. You assume that all gods are as personal as the Judeo-Christian Yahweh. But that is the exception not the rule. If you compare the Judeo-Christian Yahweh who chooses His people with Krishna who is utterly impersonal to even his most personal friends and lovers, you will see what I mean. Personally(!!) I find the theism-deism dichotomy absurd, but if you must make it, most of the world's religions are more deistic than Judeo-Christianity. That is why to me you talk as a Christian whether you realize or not.

@Rushi The entirety of your disagreement you have with me seems to be based on you using a different definition of "theism", even though I made it very clear that I'm not using that definition. So you're just flat-out wrong about my assumptions and bias. But I'm not particularly interested in arguing semantics.

@Rushi - "Why/How is that programming language not part of the dream" - Of course, it is. A Russian matryoshka, nested worlds of dreams. But it does not affect our knowledge.

The usual term is spiritual. Another term that comes from 19th century British religious philosophy is deist.

"A theist is the opposite of an atheist. Theists believe in the existence of a god or gods. The word deist refers to someone who believes in God. But a deist believes that while God created the universe, natural laws determine how the universe plays out" - I don't think it fits the view of the world in a computer simulator.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance: No, it doesn't.
